# how to pull selenium/hub from docker?

Tags: windows, docker, selenium-grid

when I try to pull selenium/hub from docker hub, it gives this error.

[Error- click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te8zI.png)

I am using Windows 10 Pro. how can I pull the selenium hub?

Comment: Please don't post a picture of a command line - copy and paste the output.  And it looks pretty obvious from the error - you can't run or build a Linux container on a Windows host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have docker for windows installed on win10 it has windows container mode and linux container mode. you need to right click and switch to linux containers before you pull your selenium images...

goto your system-tray and right click on the docker icon and then choose Switch To Linux Containers as shown in the picture below.

[image: Switching to Linux Containers]