# How to fix an issue with "Image OS 'Linux' cannot be used on this platform" on Docker Pull?

Tags: docker

I recently installed Docker EE on Windows Server 2016 and trying to pull an image from docker repo. But I am getting an error and cannot pull the image. How do you pull linux Docker images into Windows Server 2016?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker pull elgalu/selenium
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from elgalu/selenium
image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
```

Comment: Did you enable HyperV? it is mandatory for running Linux containers on Windows Server...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pull selenium/hub from docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254532/how-to-pull-selenium-hub-from-docker)

Comment: @lhdamiani I just asked our infrastructure team to enable the Hyper-V for that server. Will get back to you if I am successful with pulling the container afterwards.

Comment: @vijay the post you've linked is having the problem on Windows Pro who has Docker desktop. My issue is on Windows Server 2016 with Docker EE installed. On EE you dont get the desktop app. So, it is not the same problem. I think once I have Hyper-V enabled, the issue will be resolved as per the comment above.

Comment: @lhdamiani I made sure Hyper-V enabled and still seeing the same error. Any other ideas?